# Mysql Connector not working for Eclipse Juno on JDK 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, mysql-connector

I have a Java program which does CRUD on a MySQL database.

For this, I had been using :

```
Eclipse Indigo
Java 1.6
MySql-Connector-java-5.1.19-bin.jar
```

I tried executing the same code on a *new* machine with :

```
Eclipse Juno
Java 1.7
MySql-Connector-java-5.1.19-bin.jar.
```

I've added the MySql connector to the Build Path of the project in Eclipse Juno.

However, the ant build fails with errors about about missing classes and packages which should be picked up from the connector :

```
Buildfile: /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/build/build.xml
init:
compile:
[javac] Compiling 14 source files to /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/work/classes
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:3: error: package com.mysql.jdbc does not exist
[javac] import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
[javac]                      ^
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:4: error: package com.mysql.jdbc does not exist
[javac] import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
[javac]                      ^
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:5: error: package com.mysql.jdbc does not exist
[javac] import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet;
[javac]                      ^
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             PreparedStatement stat = (PreparedStatement)connect.prepareStatement(query2);
[javac]             ^
[javac]   symbol:   class PreparedStatement
[javac]   location: class UserDB
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             PreparedStatement stat = (PreparedStatement)connect.prepareStatement(query2);
[javac]                                       ^
[javac]   symbol:   class PreparedStatement
[javac]   location: class UserDB
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             PreparedStatement stat = (PreparedStatement)connect.prepareStatement(query2);
[javac]                                                                ^
[javac]   symbol:   method prepareStatement(String)
[javac]   location: variable connect of type Connection
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             ResultSet result = (ResultSet) stat.executeQuery();
[javac]             ^
[javac]   symbol:   class ResultSet
[javac]   location: class UserDB
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             ResultSet result = (ResultSet) stat.executeQuery();
[javac]                                 ^
[javac]   symbol:   class ResultSet
[javac]   location: class UserDB
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                 PreparedStatement preparedStmt = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement(query);
[javac]                 ^
[javac]   symbol:   class PreparedStatement
[javac]   location: class UserDB
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                 PreparedStatement preparedStmt = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement(query);
[javac]                                                   ^
[javac]   symbol:   class PreparedStatement
[javac]   location: class UserDB
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                 PreparedStatement preparedStmt = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement(query);
[javac]                                                                             ^
[javac]   symbol:   method prepareStatement(String)
[javac]   location: variable connect of type Connection
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                 PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement("Insert into user values (?,?,?);");
[javac]                 ^
[javac]   symbol:   class PreparedStatement
[javac]   location: class UserDB
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                 PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement("Insert into user values (?,?,?);");
[javac]                                                ^
[javac]   symbol:   class PreparedStatement
[javac]   location: class UserDB
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                 PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement("Insert into user values (?,?,?);");
[javac]                                                                          ^
[javac]   symbol:   method prepareStatement(String)
[javac]   location: variable connect of type Connection
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement(query);
[javac]             ^
[javac]   symbol:   class PreparedStatement
[javac]   location: class UserDB
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement(query);
[javac]                                            ^
[javac]   symbol:   class PreparedStatement
[javac]   location: class UserDB
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement(query);
[javac]                                                                      ^
[javac]   symbol:   method prepareStatement(String)
[javac]   location: variable connect of type Connection
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             ResultSet result = (ResultSet) statement.executeQuery();
[javac]             ^
[javac]   symbol:   class ResultSet
[javac]   location: class UserDB
[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             ResultSet result = (ResultSet) statement.executeQuery();
[javac]                                 ^
[javac]   symbol:   class ResultSet
[javac]   location: class UserDB
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The build path defined in eclipse is not necessarily the path your ant build file does use. Maybe you have to modify the build.xml?!

Comment: [link]http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10031542/build.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a cue from **[this](http://bit.ly/RliE2y)** question :

Assuming that you have a compile target in your build.xml which looks similar to this :

```
<!-- Compile application -->
  <target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" debug="yes" includeantruntime="false">
      <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </javac>
  </target>
```

All we need for successful compilation is to define the classpath so that it includes all the jars in the lib directory of the project, like so :

```
  <path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
  </path>
```

I understand from your question that you have added a reference to the connector jar inside the Eclipse project. You could try the above suggestion *after* copying the connector jar inside the Eclipse project's lib folder.

Alternatively, though not a great suggestion in my opinion, you could export the project as an Ant Build and check the build.xml thus generated. This can be done by going to File -> Export, typing 'ant' to filter and then choosing 'Ant Buildfiles', like so :

[image: Export as Ant BuildFiles]

Comment: Thanks. That worked to some extent. Reduced the number of errors from 19 to 5.

Comment: <pre>[javac] /home/rudra/Softwares/openfire/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/UserDB.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
           [javac] import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet;
            [javac]                      ^
            [javac]   symbol:   class ResultSet
            [javac]   location: package com.mysql.jdbc</pre>

Comment: @AshutoshJindal- Thanks Very much. Finally the problem related to ResultSet is solved. I was using `code`com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet. When I changed to `code`java.sql.ResultSet, there was no error.